# Difference between focus and blur in fireevent

Tags: selenium

What is the difference between focus and blur in fireEvent of Selenium?
Kindly,help.

In which situations do we use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a Selenium **specific** question...

The `focus` event is fired when an element *gains* focus.

The `blur` event is fired when an element *loses* focus.